# How to flush route table in windows?

Tags: windows, winsock, routes

I am trying to write a program that changes the default gateway of network time by time. But it seems that there are caches on the route table in every process so that I cannot control the network behavior accurately. Can I just flush route table to that process?

For example if I executed an Iexplore.exe first, then changed the default gateway to a Korean vpn, IE still went to amercia default gateway. But if I change the default gateway first and then execute Iexplore.exe, it went to Korea.

So how can I flush the route table cache? Thanks.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

From command prompt as admin run:

```
netsh interface ip delete destinationcache
```

Works on Win7.

Comment: Worked for me on Win 10 powershell

Answer (score 5):

route -f causes damage. So we need to either disconnect the correct parts of the routing table or find out how to rebuild it.

Comment: If we have DHCP giving the correct routes then it's fine. I have used that and reconnected my wired and wireless networks and I'm fine.

Comment: route -f is very dangerous if your vm is in the cloud, you loose all possible access unless you restore a backup.

Answer (score 4):

You can open a command prompt and do a

```
route print
```

and see your current routing table.

You can modify it by

```
route add    d.d.d.d mask m.m.m.m g.g.g.g 
route delete d.d.d.d mask m.m.m.m g.g.g.g 
route change d.d.d.d mask m.m.m.m g.g.g.g
```

these seem to work

I run a ping d.d.d.d -t change the route and it changes.  (my test involved routing to a dead route and the ping stopped)

Answer (score 0):

In Microsoft Windows, you can go through by **route -f** command to delete your current Gateway, check **route / ?** for more advance option, like add / delete etc and also can write a batch to add route on specific time as well but if you need to delete IP cache, then you have the option to use **arp** command.
**THIS WILL REMOVE ALL YOUR ROUTES. Rebooting Windows won't help. You will have to set them manually**

Comment: The route -f command causes the gateway to be permanently lost. You should definitely include that in your answer.

Comment: This completely destroyed my VPN configurations. I had to uninstall and reinstall the VPN clients to fix it. Just rebooting Windows didn't help.